# Drawing the p,T-diagram with TikZ/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to draw a p,T-diagram with TikZ using pgfplots as shown in the picture. All I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=1.5,
    ticks=none,
    axis lines = left,
    axis line style={shorten >=-10pt},
    xlabel={Temperatur $T$},
    ylabel={Druck $p$},
    xmax=100,
    ymax=100,
]
\addplot [
    no markers,
    domain=0:28.3, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    line width=1pt,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\scriptsize| Sublimationsdruckkurve},
            raise=1ex,
            text align={center},
            }
        },
    ]
    {37/104976*x^3 + 25/5832*x^2};
\addplot [
    no markers,
    domain=28.3:54, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    line width=1pt,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\scriptsize| Dampfdruckkurve},
            raise=1ex,
            text align={center}
            }
        },
    ]
    {37/104976*x^3 + 25/5832*x^2};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(9.86,37/104976*9.86^3 + 25/5832*9.86^2)(11.3,100)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    line width=1pt,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\scriptsize| Schmelzdruckkurve},
            raise=1ex,
            text align={center}
            }
        },
    ]
    coordinates{(18.9,37/104976*18.9^3 + 25/5832*18.9^2)(21.5,100)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(28.3,37/104976*28.3^3 + 25/5832*28.3^2)(31.5,100)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(35.7,37/104976*35.7^3 + 25/5832*35.7^2)(39.9,100)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(45.0,37/104976*45.0^3 + 25/5832*45.0^2)(49.4,100)};
\addplot [
    no markers,
    domain=54:100, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    {37/104976*x^3 + 25/5832*x^2};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(16.9,37/104976*16.9^3 + 25/5832*16.9^2)(100,7.23)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(30.9,37/104976*30.9^3 + 25/5832*30.9^2)(100,28.0)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(37.6,37/104976*37.6^3 + 25/5832*37.6^2)(100,48.5)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(42.2,37/104976*42.2^3 + 25/5832*42.2^2)(100,66.4)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(47.0,37/104976*47.0^3 + 25/5832*47.0^2)(100,89.0)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(50.6,37/104976*50.6^3 + 25/5832*50.6^2)(80.8,100)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am struggeling with the text for the isochoric lines, the x axis ticks for T_tr and T_K and the axis symbols p and T left and below the arrows. Besides, the text above the curves should not overlap with other lines. I am missing a background option. Maybe somebody can help me out?

[image: p,T-diagram]

Comment: As the lines are, well, just lines, you don't need `\addplot`, you can use `\draw` like this: `\draw (x_1,y_1) -- (x_2,y_2) node[above, sloped, pos=0.5] {$z=4n$};`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fairly close.

- The axis labels have been moved by modifying the `every axis x label` and `every axis y label` styles, see the `axis` options.
- Ticks are added by changing `ticks=none` to `ytick=\empty` and adding `xtick={28.9,54},xticklabels={$T_{\mathrm{Tr}}$, $T_{\mathrm{K}}$}`. The dashed lines are drawn with a `ycomb` plot, see the last `\addplot`.
- The labels on the lines are added with `node[pos=<fraction>,sloped,above]{$v=Nv_K$};`. Some trial and error to get nice values for `pos`.
- Two `postactions` to get `Sublimationsdruckkurve` in two lines. To avoid the overprinting of the line, I added a `shorten <=5ex` to the offending `\addplot`. Similar for the line over `Dampfdruckkurve`.
- Nodes with `pin` or `label` added to get the `Tripelpunkt` and `K` labels.
- Festkörper, Flussigkeit and Gasphase are added as nodes filled with white (see end of `axis` environment).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale=1.5,
    ytick=\empty,
    axis lines = left,
    axis line style={shorten >=-10pt},
    xlabel={Temperatur $T$},
    ylabel={Druck $p$},
    xmax=100,
    ymax=100,
    xtick={18.9,54},
    xticklabels={$T_{\mathit{tr}}$, $T_{K}$},
    every axis x label/.style={anchor=north east,at={(1,0)},xshift=10pt},
    every axis y label/.style={anchor=north east,at={(0,1)},yshift=10pt},
]
\addplot [
    no markers,
    domain=0:18.9, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    line width=1pt,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\scriptsize| Sublimations-},
            raise=3ex,
            text align={center},
            },
        },
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\scriptsize| druckkurve},
            raise=1ex,
            text align={center},
            },
        },
    ]    {37/104976*x^3 + 25/5832*x^2} node[inner sep=0pt,pin={[pin distance=1cm,font=\scriptsize,inner sep=1pt]3:Tripelpunkt}]{};
\addplot [
    no markers,
    domain=18.9:54, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    line width=1pt,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\scriptsize| Dampfdruckkurve},
            raise=1ex,
            text align={center},
            }
        },
    ]
    {37/104976*x^3 + 25/5832*x^2} node[inner sep=0pt,label={[font=\footnotesize]10:$K$}]{};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    shorten <=5ex
    ]
    coordinates{(9.86,37/104976*9.86^3 + 25/5832*9.86^2)(11.3,100)} node[pos=0.9,sloped,above] {$v=\mathrm{const.}$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    line width=1pt,
    postaction={
        decorate,
        decoration={
            text along path,
            text={|\scriptsize| Schmelzdruckkurve},
            raise=1ex,
            text align={center},
            }
        },
    ]
    coordinates{(18.9,37/104976*18.9^3 + 25/5832*18.9^2)(21.5,100)};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(28.3,37/104976*28.3^3 + 25/5832*28.3^2)(31.5,100)} node[pos=0.8,sloped,above]{$v=0.4v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    shorten <=6ex
    ]
    coordinates{(35.7,37/104976*35.7^3 + 25/5832*35.7^2)(39.9,100)} node[pos=0.77,sloped,above]{$v=0.5v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(45.0,37/104976*45.0^3 + 25/5832*45.0^2)(49.4,100)} node[pos=0.7,sloped,above]{$v=0.7v_k$};
\addplot [
    no markers,
    domain=54:100, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    {37/104976*x^3 + 25/5832*x^2} node [pos=0.05,sloped,above] {$v=v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(16.9,37/104976*16.9^3 + 25/5832*16.9^2)(100,7.23)} node[pos=0.8,sloped,above]{$v=40v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(30.9,37/104976*30.9^3 + 25/5832*30.9^2)(100,28.0)} node[pos=0.75,sloped,above]{$v=10v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(37.6,37/104976*37.6^3 + 25/5832*37.6^2)(100,48.5)}node[pos=0.7,sloped,above]{$v=6v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(42.2,37/104976*42.2^3 + 25/5832*42.2^2)(100,66.4)}node[pos=0.65,sloped,above]{$v=4v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(47.0,37/104976*47.0^3 + 25/5832*47.0^2)(100,89.0)}node[pos=0.55,sloped,above]{$v=3v_k$};
\addplot+[
    smooth,
    no markers,
    color=black,
    style=solid,
    ]
    coordinates{(50.6,37/104976*50.6^3 + 25/5832*50.6^2)(80.8,100)} node[pos=0.6,sloped,above]{$v=2v_k$};


\addplot [black,mark=*,mark options={draw=black,solid,fill=white},densely dashed,ycomb,samples at={18.9,54}] {37/104976*x^3 + 25/5832*x^2};

\node [align=center,fill=white] at (rel axis cs:0.1,0.7){Fest-\\körper};
\node [align=center,fill=white] at (rel axis cs:0.35,0.55){Flüssigkeit};
\node [align=center,fill=white] at (rel axis cs:0.7,0.36){Gasphase};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is perfect and you really helped me out.